# Is there a way to have two join tables associate the same two classes in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Long time listener, first time caller. I'm trying to create two associations between the same database tables, Chatrooms and Users. What I have so far is a has_many through relationship where a Chatroom has many Users through Messages. This part works fine. What I want to do is to create a second join table that connects Chatrooms to Users, through a join table called Chatroom_players. So what I'd like is for Chatroom.first.users to get me users through the messages join table and Chatroom.first.players to get me everyone from the chatroom_players join table. The reason I want this is so that I can maintain user presence even if a user hasn't written any messages in the chat, also so that a user can leave the room but maintain his or her messages in the chat.

Here is what I have so far that does not work:

chatroom.rb:

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :messages

  has_many :chatroom_players
  has_many :users, through: :chatroom_players
end
```

message.rb:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 200}
end
```

chatroom_player.rb

```
class ChatroomPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chatrooms, through: :messages

  has_many :chatroom_players
  has_many :chatrooms, through: :chatroom_players
end
```

chatroom_players migration:

```
class AddChatroomPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :chatroom_players do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :chatroom, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.boolean :creator, default: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different names for the associations:

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :messages
  has_many :chatroom_players
  # this is a separate association to users through the
  # chatroom_players table.
  has_many :participants, 
     through: :chatroom_players, 
     source: :user, # what association on chatroom_players to use
     class_name: 'User' # since it cannot be deduced automatically
end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! The other thing I needed to do, which I did in your style, was to associate chatrooms to users as games, so now users have games and chatrooms, and chatrooms have users and players.

Comment: has_many :games,
       through: :chatroom_players,
       source: :chatroom,
       class_name: "Chatroom"